# Binding Rails 4 form with model without table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a Java background. I used to bind POJO (Plain Old Java Object) classes to forms. POJO's are not associated with any database table.
I was trying to do the same in Rails. I created following model:

```
class Email

def initialize
   @to_email = ''
   @name = ''
   @subject = ''
   @message = ''
end

end
```

And following form:

```
<h1>Please fill up the form</h1>
<%= form_for @email, :url => {:action => 'sendemail'} do |f| %>
<p>
  Name<br/><%= f.text_field 'name' %>
</p>
<p>
  Email<br/><%= f.text_field 'to_email' %>
</p>
<p>
  Subject<br/><%= f.text_field 'subject' %>
</p>
<p>
  Message<br/><%= f.text_area 'message' %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.submit "Submit Data" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

And here is my controller:

```
class EmailController < ApplicationController

def capture
   @email = Email.new
end

def sendemail
   @email = Email.create(email_params)

   MandrillMailer.send_email(@email.to_email, @email.name, @email.subject, @email.message).deliver
end

def email_params
   params.require(:email).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :email)
end

end
```

The error I get is: **undefined method `model_name' for #**

I tried this URL as well but could not get through

http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model

In this case my model was:

```
class Email

def self.columns()
   @columns ||= [];      # || represents concatenation
end

def self.column(name, sql_type=nil, default=nil, null=true)
   columns << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(name.to_s, default, sql_type.to_s, null)
end

column :to_email, :string
column :name, :string
column :subject, :string
column :message, :text

end
```

The error in this case is:

```
undefined method `model_name' for #<Email:0x49f5b40>
```

This is indicating for `<%= form_for @email, :url => {:action => 'sendemail'} do |f| %>` in the view

If I write the model class as:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
```

then I get the error:

> undefined method `type_cast_from_database' for "string":String

Comment: And? What is the problem?

Comment: Hi Meier, I updated the question to point all the errors I get, thanks

Comment: Can you show the whole backtrace of the error msg. I need the line numbers as well to point out whats happening.

Answer (score 1):

I updated my model class with this and it worked

```
class Email
   include ActiveModel::Model

   attr_accessor :name
   attr_accessor :to_email
   attr_accessor :subject
   attr_accessor :message

end
```

I created a post for this

http://ashutoshpandey.in/creating-table-less-models-in-rails-4/

Answer (score -1):

Your first error is probably thrown by `form_for(@email ....)`

(why do I need to guess this, as this should be just in the stack trace of the error message?)

The `form_for` want to find out what this `@email`-object is, it asks it by calling `model_name`, and your plain ruby object does not respond. Later, your object will also not respond to the `create` method. And your object also does not implement validations.

There are two solutions:

1. If you want to stick with basic objects, do not use `form_for`, use `form_tag`.
   you need to handle the parameters one by one then.
2. Include the [ActiveModel](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) module in your method. This way, your objects behave like a ActiveRecord without the database stuff. From the documentation:

> Includes the required interface for an object to interact with
>   ActionPack, using different ActiveModel modules. It includes model
>   name introspections, conversions, translations and validations.
>   Besides that, it allows you to initialize the object with a hash of
>   attributes, pretty much like ActiveRecord does.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html

The errors at the end are because the railscast is out of date.
Hint: if you see older railscasts, look at the comments.